# Button triggers neighbouring button

Tags: html, button

When I click or mouse-over on the button on the left is OK, but when I click or mouse-over on the button on the right it triggers the button on the left. Why? And how to fix this?

[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]

Bug in browser or bug in script?

```
<label>
    <span>Bestand:</span>
    <select name="bestand">
        <option value=".htaccess" disabled>.htaccess</option>
        <option value="asdf.rar" >asdf.rar</option>
        <option value="voorbeeld.php" >voorbeeld.php</option>
    </select>
     of  
    <input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" /> 
    <select name="convert">
        <option selected="selected">Niet converten</option>
        <option>Convert naar rar</option>
        <option>Convert naar zip</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

EDIT:

This will fix it:

```
<label style="display:inline-block; float:right;">
of  
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="file_upload" /> 
    <select name="convert">
        <option value="not" selected="selected">Niet converten</option>
        <option value="rar">Convert naar rar</option>
        <option value="zip">Convert naar zip</option>
     </select>
</label>
<label>
    <span>Bestand:</span>
    <select name="bestand">
        <option value=".htaccess" disabled>.htaccess</option>
        <option value="asdf.rar" >asdf.rar</option>
        <option value="voorbeeld.php" >voorbeeld.php</option>
    </select>
</label>
```

But it feels not ok..

Comment: The problem is that the dropdown indicator on the left stays blue?

Comment: @RyPope Well not stays. Only when I click or mouse-over on the right button.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>DOCS about `label` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label</sup>

That's what `labels` are supposed to do. They are an *action* wrapper for an action element.
To prevent this behavior use the following <sub>(not a suggestion)</sub>:

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/Ihodira/1/edit)

```
label {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**otherwise use `<label>` the way it's meant to be used:**

> Label elements should be used as a wrapper for only **one** action element. If not used as a wrapper, it can be assigned to an `ID` element using the `for` property matching that ID value.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a label tag around all those controls? A label tag should only enclose the label for a single element. In your case:

```
<label for="bestand">Bestand:</label>
<select name="bestand" id="bestand">
```

And, since you can style labels with css the same as any other element, such as span, there is no need for the span:

```
label#bestand{font-style:italic;color:blue;}
```

This is most likely your problem, since if you click on the label it will trigger the control to which it is related.

```
The <label> element does not render as anything special for the user. 
However, it provides a usability improvement for mouse users, because 
if the user clicks on the text within the <label> element, it toggles 
the control.
```

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

By surrounding multiple controls with a label tag, the behavior you describe may occur.